# How do I keep the users inputted values after he leaves the "enter" option and make him start from were he finished of?

Tags: c

I have a certain exercise I must do. Hopefully someone understands what I have failed to do.

whenever a user presses enter, types in less than 10 integers, presses q to exit the option and then comes back, all of his input values will be gone. I want to input values to be left there until the total elements stored are 10. How do I do this?

Note! The user is not supposed to exit the application (which in this case is CMD), rather they should only be able to leave the "enter" option and still have their input values "stored".

```
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define L 10

void view(int a[])

     {
        int i;
        printf("\n Here are the currently stored values\n");  

        printf("[");
        for(i=0; i<L; i++)
            {
            printf(" %d ",a[i]);
            }
        printf("]");
     }

int enter(int a[], int n)
     {
         printf("\n Note! You can press any letter if you want to return to the main menu. \n");

         for(int i=0; i<L; i++)

            {

            int mesa;
            printf(" Enter measurement #%d (or q to quit): ", n+1);
            int check = scanf("%d",&mesa); 

            if(check)
                {
                    a[i] = mesa;
                    n++;
                }
            else
                { 
                    char temp;
                    scanf(" %c",&temp);
                    return n;
                }
            }
           return n;
     }

void compute(int a[], int n)

     {
            printf(" Computing...\n");

            //Min value
            {
                int i;
                int min = 10000;

                for (i = 0; i < L; i++)
                if(a[i] < min)
                min = a[i];

                printf("\n The min value is: %d \n", min);
            }

            //Max value
            {
                int i;
                int max = a[0];

                for (i = 0; i < L; i++) 
                if (a[i] > max) 
                max = a[i]; 

               printf(" The max value is: %d \n", max);
            }

            // Average & Normalization
            {
                float average;
                int i;
                int norm;
                int sum;

                for(i = 0; i < L; ++i)
                    {
                    sum = sum + a[i];
                    average = (float)sum / 10; //typecast - Ge en interger en tillfällig roll. På så sätt kan du säga åt programmet att du faktiskt vill ha float som svar och inte ett heltal som svar.
                    } 
                    printf(" Average value: %.2f \n", average);

                    printf(" Normalized array: [");
                for(i = 0; i < L; i++)
                    {
                    norm = a[i] - average; //average - every a[]
                    printf(" %d", (int)round(norm));
                    }
                    printf(" ]");
            }
     }

void reset(int a[])

    {
        printf(" You have chosen to reset the array. All the elements in the array will now be deleted. \n");

        //memset( a, 0, 10*sizeof(a)); <--- Kan ej användas då sizeof() funktionen läser av en variabel och inte hela arrayens storlek.
        memset( a, 0, 10*sizeof(int*));
    }

int main()

{
    char command;
    int a[L];

    printf(" Hello and welcome to this measurement tool. In this program you will be able to type in and analyze data.\n");
    printf(" In the section below, you can choose a letter v,e,c,r or q to do certain things. More information will be provided down below.\n");
    printf("\n v(View) - Displays currently stored values.");
    printf("\n e(Enter) - Allows you to store values. ");
    printf("\n c(Compute) - Displays the maxiumum, minimum, normalized and average value of those which are stored.");
    printf("\n r(Reset) - Deletes all stored values.");
    printf("\n q(Quit) - Exits the program. \n");
    printf("\n Please choose one of the commands above: ");

    do
    {
      int n = 0;
      scanf(" %c",&command);
      switch(command)
       {
            case 'v' : view(a);break;
            case 'e' : enter(a,n);break;
            case 'c' : compute(a,n);break;
            case 'r' : reset(a);break;
            default : printf("\n Please choose one of the options given.\n");break;
            case 'q' : 
                    {
                    printf(" Want to exit? Confirmation needed. Press q again to exit.");
                    scanf(" %c",&command);
                    }   
        }
            printf("\n VECRQ?: ");
    } while(command != 'q');
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Reading and entering values seems fine.  What is your input, expected output, and actual output?

Comment: `case 'e': n = enter(a, n); break;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `main()`, move the declaration of `n` outside the loop:

```
int n = 0;
do
{
    ...
```

Update `n` when you call `enter()`:

```
n = enter(a,n);
```

In the `enter` function, start your loop from `n`:

```
for(int i=n; i<L; i++)
```

Comment: Omg...Dude. Thank you. Thank you so much man. I have been sitting with this for 2 days, couldnt figure out what to do. I wish you the very best from the bottom of my heart. I am really grateful man, thanks